# Ошибка, понимаете ли...

Tags: php, mysql

Довольно глупая ситуация, но я на ней завис.

```
mysql_query("insert into first (nazv ,text) values ({$pole},'{$text}')") or die (mysql_error());
```

- $pole - поле типа text
- $text - поле типа textarea

В чем ошибка?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

text - зарезервированное слово вроде как.

```
mysql_query("insert into `first` (`nazv` ,`text`) values ('{$pole}','{$text}');") or die (mysql_error());
```

Попробуйте так.

UPDATE:

```
<?
if (@$_POST['save']){
  $text=$_POST['content'];
  $pole=$_POST['pole'];
  if (!$text || !$pole) {
    echo ("Поле не заполнено");
    } else {
    mysql_query($q = 'INSERT INTO first (`nazv`,`text`) VALUES (\''.mysql_real_escape_string($pole).'\', \''.mysql_real_escape_string($pole).'\');') or die (mysql_error().'<br />Query: '.$q);
    }
  }
?>
```

Comment: Не хочет пишет
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''')' at line 1
И смена названия поля тоже ничего не дала
После последнего изменения ничего не вывела. Может я что не так делаю? Хочу всего лишь проверку полей сделать

`
if (@$_POST['save']){
$text=$_POST['content'];
$pole=$_POST['pole'];
if ($text&&$pole===""){
echo ("Поле не заполнено");}
mysql_query("insert into `first` (`nazv` ,`text`) values ({$pole},'{$text}')") or die (mysql_error());
?>
`

Comment: Обновил

Comment: После последнего изменения ничего не вывела. Может я что не так делаю? Хочу всего лишь проверку полей сделать
if (@$_POST['save']){
$text=$_POST['content'];
$pole=$_POST['pole'];
if ($text&&$pole===""){
echo ("Поле не заполнено");}
mysql_query("insert intofirst(nazv,text) values ({$pole},'{$text}')") or die (mysql_error());
?>

Comment: Еще обновил. Несколько ошибок и оплошностей)

Comment: СПАСИБО большое. Жму галку.